# Is it perspective or prospective?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The research engineer Whitney Sample in the following video says "*It keeps me in **PUS-PECTIVE.***" **Is it *perspective* or *prospective***, i am confused here

See exactly 4:23 minute of the video in the link; http://edition.cnn.com/video/data/2.0/video/world/2014/03/20/spc-vital-signs-3d-printing-wrex.cnn.html

What does it mean? I mean *perspective* means *a particular attitude towards or way of regarding something; a point of view.* and *prospective* means *expected or expecting to be the specified thing in the future,* according to the Google search engine dictionary. ***But I don't know how to match*** either meaning to the context in the video.

Finally, in the above line I asked *But I dont know how to match* . **How to replace this phrase with appropriate words?**

Comment: It's *"It keeps me in perspective"*, meaning: I can be in a good position to look at the issue. (Sorry if it's not very precise. I just listened to that sentence.)

Answer (score 2):

The person in the interview was talking about how the work they've done isn't any amazing achievement (as far as I could tell from the context of the video) but the family is speaking from a different viewpoint, saying they've made an achievement nonetheless.

He is talking about a different *perspective*: he is looking at the work as if he failed to reach a goal, but the family shows him a viewpoint where they have made progress anyway. That's how the word fits into context.

As for the 'But I don't know how to match' phrase... I would just ask, why would you want to change it? It's a fine phrase xD

But, of course, that won't get me an upvoted answer, so have a look at these alternatives:

> I don't know how to **link** these words with the context.
>
> I don't know how the context is **connected** to these words.
>
> I don't know if these words **have anything to do with** the context.
>
> I am not yet aware of how said context warrants the employment of said words in said fashion for said purpose from said perspective.

Comment: +1! But..but..you didn't work either "associate" or "cross-reference" into the final sentence! :)